# D3 JS append to div weird result

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

Hello i am stuck with a rather weird issue. I have a graph that works when its appended to the body. When i change this to appending to a div this happens:
Normal
![normal state]https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCiuG.jpg
Appended to div
![div state]https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDdsC.jpg

I noticed the axis arent drawn correctly but no clue how to fix that.

One time it stays normal and on update it becomes small with the correct axis.

My code:

```
// Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
var margin = {top: 15, right: 10, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 400 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 220 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Parse the date / time
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;

// Set the ranges
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

// Define the axes
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
    .orient("bottom").ticks(5);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
    .orient("left").ticks(5);

// Define the line
var valueline = d3.svg.line()
.interpolate("basis") 
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.close); });

// Define the second line
var valueline2 = d3.svg.line()
.interpolate("basis") 
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.open); });

// Define the second line
var valueline3 = d3.svg.line()
.interpolate("basis") 
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.open2); });

// Define the second line
var valueline4 = d3.svg.line()
.interpolate("basis") 
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.open3); });

// Adds the svg canvas
var svg = d3.select("#biggraph")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Get the initial data
d3.tsv("data/data2.tsv", function(error, data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
        d.close = +d.close;
        d.open = +d.open;
        d.open2 = +d.open2;
        d.open3 = +d.open3;
    });

    // Scale the range of the data
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return Math.max(d.close, d.open, d.open2, d.open3); })]);

    // Add the valueline path.
    svg.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", valueline(data));

     // Add the valueline2 path.
     svg.append("path")     
        .attr("class", "line2")
        .style("stroke", "red")
        .attr("d", valueline2(data));  

     // Add the valueline3 path.
     svg.append("path")     
        .attr("class", "line3")
        .style("stroke", "#FF6600")
        .attr("d", valueline3(data)); 


     // Add the valueline4 path.
     svg.append("path")     
        .attr("class", "line4")
        .style("stroke", "green")
        .attr("d", valueline4(data)); 

    // Add the X Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    // Add the Y Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis);

});

// ** Update data section (Called from the onclick)
function updateData() {

    // Get the data again
    d3.tsv("data/data-alt2.tsv", function(error, data) {
        data.forEach(function(d) {
            d.date = parseDate(d.date);
            d.close = +d.close;
            d.open = +d.open;
            d.open2 = +d.open2;
            d.open3 = +d.open3;
        });

        // Scale the range of the data again 
        x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
        y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return Math.max(d.close, d.open, d.open2, d.open3); })]);

    // Select the section we want to apply our changes to
    var svg = d3.select("#biggraph").transition();

    // Make the changes
        svg.select(".line")   // change the line
            .duration(750)
            .attr("d", valueline(data));
        svg.select(".line2")   // change the line
            .duration(750)
            .attr("d", valueline2(data));
        svg.select(".line3")   // change the line
            .duration(750)
            .attr("d", valueline3(data));
        svg.select(".line4")   // change the line
            .duration(750)
            .attr("d", valueline4(data));

        svg.select(".x.axis") // change the x axis
            .duration(750)
            .call(xAxis);
        svg.select(".y.axis") // change the y axis
            .duration(750)
            .call(yAxis);


    });
}



// ** Update data section (Called from the onclick)
function revertData() {

    // Get the data again
    d3.tsv("data/data2.tsv", function(error, data) {
        data.forEach(function(d) {
            d.date = parseDate(d.date);
            d.close = +d.close;
            d.open = +d.open;
            d.open2 = +d.open2;
            d.open3 = +d.open3;
        });

        // Scale the range of the data again 
        x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
        y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return Math.max(d.close, d.open, d.open2, d.open3); })]);;

    // Select the section we want to apply our changes to
    var svg = d3.select("#biggraph").transition();

    // Make the changes
        svg.select(".line")   // change the line
            .duration(750)
            .attr("d", valueline(data));
        svg.select(".line2")   // change the line
            .duration(750)
            .attr("d", valueline2(data));
        svg.select(".line3")   // change the line
            .duration(750)
            .attr("d", valueline3(data));
        svg.select(".line4")   // change the line
            .duration(750)
            .attr("d", valueline4(data));
        svg.select(".x.axis") // change the x axis
            .duration(750)
            .call(xAxis);
        svg.select(".y.axis") // change the y axis
            .duration(750)
            .call(yAxis);

    });
}


// ** Update data section (Called from the onclick)
function updateData48h() {

    // Get the data again
    d3.tsv("data/data48h.tsv", function(error, data) {
        data.forEach(function(d) {
            d.date = parseDate(d.date);
            d.close = +d.close;
            d.open = +d.open;
            d.open2 = +d.open2;
            d.open3 = +d.open3;
        });

        // Scale the range of the data again 
        x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
        y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return Math.max(d.close, d.open, d.open2, d.open3); })]);

    // Select the section we want to apply our changes to
    var svg = d3.select("#biggraph").transition();

    // Make the changes
        svg.select(".line")   // change the line
            .duration(750)
            .attr("d", valueline(data));
        svg.select(".line2")   // change the line
            .duration(750)
            .attr("d", valueline2(data));
        svg.select(".line3")   // change the line
            .duration(750)
            .attr("d", valueline3(data));
        svg.select(".line4")   // change the line
            .duration(750)
            .attr("d", valueline4(data));
        svg.select(".x.axis") // change the x axis
            .duration(750)
            .call(xAxis);
        svg.select(".y.axis") // change the y axis
            .duration(750)
            .call(yAxis);

    });
}

// ** Update data section (Called from the onclick)
function updateData24h() {

    // Get the data again
    d3.tsv("data/data24h.tsv", function(error, data) {
        data.forEach(function(d) {
            d.date = parseDate(d.date);
            d.close = +d.close;
            d.open = +d.open;
            d.open2 = +d.open2;
            d.open3 = +d.open3;
        });

        // Scale the range of the data again 
        x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
        y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return Math.max(d.close, d.open, d.open2, d.open3); })]);

    // Select the section we want to apply our changes to
    var svg = d3.select("#biggraph").transition();

    // Make the changes
        svg.select(".line")   // change the line
            .duration(750)
            .attr("d", valueline(data));
        svg.select(".line2")   // change the line
            .duration(750)
            .attr("d", valueline2(data));
        svg.select(".line3")   // change the line
            .duration(750)
            .attr("d", valueline3(data));
        svg.select(".line4")   // change the line
            .duration(750)
            .attr("d", valueline4(data));
        svg.select(".x.axis") // change the x axis
            .duration(750)
            .call(xAxis);
        svg.select(".y.axis") // change the y axis
            .duration(750)
            .call(yAxis);

    });
}
```

Any clues would be much appriciated

Comment: That's sort of hilarious. Can you pass along the styling around #biggraph? I have it working fine here with dummy data: http://jsfiddle.net/hZ4Fe/

Comment: Thank you for checking Chris. Its getting even weirder. The normal state is working on the firstload. Afterwards same issue. The update isnt working. Still doing the same thing. I will try to put up a jsfiddle for it. Here is the styling for #biggraph #biggraph{ position: inherit; width: 100%; height:100%; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the anwser to the problem. It was an issue with another data stream on the same page. Renaming it has solved the issue.