# D3.js - Appending to <div> not working

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am facing a very strange problem.

If I try to append rectangles to `body` it works fine. However, if I try to append to `<div>` -  it does not work

What makes it even strange is that, on Fiddler both versions work.

https://jsfiddle.net/ek6xmbs2/

However, on my laptop

```
d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
```

does not work (displays a blank screen). While the below works

```
d3.select("body").append("svg")
```

Saw a similar issue here

[D3 JS append to div weird result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17116650/d3-js-append-to-div-weird-result)

However, can't make out from the response as to what fixed it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blank screen is due to exceptions thrown within your [Original Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ek6xmbs2/). Open your dev tools and notice the error trying to load d3.js. Specifically...

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/' was
>   loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script
>   'http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js'. This request has been blocked; the
>   content must be served over HTTPS.

This of course throws the immediate exception of

> Uncaught ReferenceError: d3 is not defined

So, outside the scope of this not working in a fiddle-the code works fine.

```
d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
```

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/93xjmzxL/) - Works as expected

What's different? I change my `<script>` source per errors relayed to me

---

### Edit

Per discussion, code referenced is likely firing before the DOM is loaded. Wrapping code with the following will solve the issue

```
window.onload = function () {
    // ...
    d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
    // ...
}
```

[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/058zu7g2/) - DOM Ready

Comment: The error in the fiddler console is due to D3 JS not being loaded correctly. However, this is not a problem in my laptop. Ironically, despite of the console errors related to loading fiddler JS, it works fine in fiddler. Even though there are no errors in my local copy, it still does not work when 'div' is referenced

Comment: Is this firing before your DOM content is loaded? Try wrapping your code with `window.onload = function ()
{ }` @kayasa

Comment: That worked. Thanks! Just curious why this didn't cause a problem when appending to <body>

Comment: @kayasa I have edited my answer with what solved this. Please be sure to accept if you have found this helpful. Also, as to the why.. it must be that `<body>` was loaded first => code executed => but `div#chart` was still not yet loaded